# The Hair means what?

Tags: word-meaning

**The hair** -- the privilege he tries to hide with retweets of Black Lives Matter. Not to sound judgy, but this guy is everything wrong with America. See, this is why I do my research. You fall for the wrong men -- bad men. You let them in. You let them hurt you.

What does THE HAIR mean here?. dialogue from a series "You".

Comment: Can you cite a source, please? And perhaps provide more context?

Comment: The guy probably has something not pleasing about his hairstyle or it's color. It could be anything, that why we need context,  either it's a terrible haircut or  there's  too much/ long/greasy/dirty or too little hair. We use the definite article "the" when both the speaker and the listener understand which "hair" they are referring to.

Comment: Please provide more context next time. We spend so much time looking up things that posters could post very easily. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's from a TV series, 'You', season 1, episode 1. The character 'Joe' is thinking about someone called 'Benji'. Joe clearly disapproves of Benji, and. it would seem, his hairstyle ('the hair'), and also his air of entitlement and his privilege. Joe considers these things to be 'everything that is wrong with America'. The 'thoughts' tell you as much about Joe as they do about Benji.

> JOE'S THOUGHTS (CONT'D)
> Benjamin J. Tuttle the third. Greenwich
> born, boarding school bred. Then onto Cornell, legacy admission seeing
> as his father is The Ben Tuttle of Tuttle Brokerage. At least two
> failed careers since college. Model. Oh boy. And co-creator of a
> busted dating app that connects people through their musical tastes
> called LOVENOTEZ. Currently CEO of Home Soda Artisanal Beverages,
> motto: "drink better by hand," which makes no sense but evokes a
> homespun quality that lines up well with a guy who wears
> six-hundred-dollar Japanese sneakers. The hair, the entitlement, the
> privilege tries to hide with retweets about Black Lives Matter. Not to
> sound judgmental, Beck, but: this guy is everything wrong with
> America.

[You 1x01 script (by Greg Berlanti & Sera Gamble)](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/You_1x01_-_Pilot.pdf)

It is common, when listing a person's qualities or features, to precede each one with a definite article, although a possessive pronoun, (his, her) is also possible:

> MICHAEL'S THOUGHTS
> My colleague Jane is wonderful. I like everything
> about her. The eyes, the face, the gentle smile that says so much, the
> always-positive attitude.